# In $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ check the polynomial $x^7+x^4+x^2+x+1$ for multiple factors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

In $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ check the polynomial $x^7+x^4+x^2+x+1$ for multiple factors.

Let $f(x)=x^7+x^4+x^2+x+1$. Then $f'(x)=7x^6+4x^3+2x+1 = x^6+1$.

Then using Euclid's algorithm I calculated $\gcd(f,f')$:

$x^7+x^4+x^2+x+1=(x^6+1)x+(x^4+x^2+1)$

$x^6+1 = (x^4+x^2+1)(x^2+1) + 0$

Hence $\gcd(f,f')=x^4+x^2+1$, so $f$ and $f'$ are not coprime, and therefore $f$ will have multiple factors.

Is this correct?

Comment: Coprime (a.k.a. *relatively prime*) means that the GCD is $1$.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct of course. I will fix this. Since the GCD is an irreducible polynomial, i.e. not a constant, therefore f and its derivative are not coprime, so f DOES have multiple factors.

Comment: For clarity, despite some deleted comments, I have double checked my calculations in the Euclidean algorithm and they are correct.

Comment: A GCD of $x^4+x^2+1$ looks right to me; it certainly cannot be $1$: $$x^7+x^4+x^2+x+1 = (x^4+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1) \\ x^6+1 = (x^4+x^2+1)(x^2+1)$$